# App getting crashed in debug mode for react native date time picker

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I installed @react-native-community/datetimepicker after which my app is crashing on launch even on debug mode. I uninstalled and re-installed the library though still getting the same. Not able to figure out the error.

Comment: Have a try by clean project and build again from XCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

Open Android Studio, and check for debug logs in Logcat (make sure you select your debuggable process)

If you do not find any error there, do the following:

1. Run fresh: `react-native run-android`

2. Reset cache: `react-native start  --reset-cache`

3. Clean Android: `cd android` —> `./gradlew clean`

Answer (score -1):

use native base datepicker

install nativebase

```
npm i nativebase --save
```

then import datePicker from nativebase

```
import {DatePicker} from 'native-base';
      <DatePicker
            defaultDate={new Date(2018, 4, 4)}
            minimumDate={new Date(2018, 1, 1)}
            maximumDate={new Date(2018, 12, 31)}
            locale={"en"}
            timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={undefined}
            modalTransparent={false}
            animationType={"fade"}
            androidMode={"default"}
            placeHolderText="Select date"
            textStyle={{ color: "green" }}
            placeHolderTextStyle={{ color: "#d3d3d3" }}
            onDateChange={this.setDate}
            disabled={false}
            />
```

for complete guide this link will help you
https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#date-picker-def-headref